# How does a server obtain the ek and iv arguments from the client, in order to RSA decrypt a message?

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography

I'm trying to use the EVP utilities in OpenSSL for RSA encryption. My goal is implement the Seal & Open method to encrypt using a public key and decrypt using a private key.

Assuming that the SSL handshake was successful and the client has the public key of the server, I want the client to seal the message before sending it.

Something like this:

```
int Crypto::rsaEncrypt(const unsigned char *msg, size_t msgLen, unsigned char **encMsg, unsigned char **ek, size_t *ekl, unsigned char **iv, size_t *ivl) {
    ...
    if(!EVP_SealInit(rsaEncryptCtx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ek, (int*)ekl, *iv, &remotePubKey, 1)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if(!EVP_SealUpdate(rsaEncryptCtx, *encMsg + encMsgLen, (int*)&blockLen, (const unsigned char*)msg, (int)msgLen)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    encMsgLen += blockLen;

    if(!EVP_SealFinal(rsaEncryptCtx, *encMsg + encMsgLen, (int*)&blockLen)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    ...
}
```

If my understanding is correct, the EVP_SealInit() will generate a public key encrypted secret key pointed to by the ek and an IV corresponding to the cipher. This is all done on the client.

When this encrypted message is sent to the server, I'll use something like this to decrypt:

```
int Crypto::rsaDecrypt(unsigned char *encMsg, size_t encMsgLen, unsigned char *ek, size_t ekl, unsigned char *iv, size_t ivl, unsigned char **decMsg) {
    ...
    if(!EVP_OpenInit(rsaDecryptCtx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ek, ekl, iv, key)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if(!EVP_OpenUpdate(rsaDecryptCtx, (unsigned char*)*decMsg + decLen, (int*)&blockLen, encMsg, (int)encMsgLen)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    decLen += blockLen;

    if(!EVP_OpenFinal(rsaDecryptCtx, (unsigned char*)*decMsg + decLen, (int*)&blockLen)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Ok, now my questions is,** if the server is calling this decrypt, how does get reference to the ek and iv (since it was created on the client)? or are those generated locally?

I referenced these following OpenSSL API docs for [Seal](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_SealInit.html) and [Open](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_OpenInit.html). And this one for the sample source code: [Crypto.cpp](https://github.com/shanet/Crypto-Example/blob/master/Crypto.cpp).

Comment: Read this incorrectly, you'll have to send them yourself together with the ciphertext, it seems to me. Note that the IV is the same as the block size for CBC mode encryption, and that the encrypted symmetric key will have the same size as the modulus. So you can statically determine the sizes if you prefix them to the ciphertext if you want to save a few bytes.

Comment: You have to synchronize `ek` and `iv` between the client and server. You should probably perform a key agreement, and then use the shared secret that results. Use the shared secret to create client and server crypto parameters like symmetric keys and iv's. Create the parameters using the shared secret from the agreement algorithm and a KDF. Use unique labels for each parameter to ensure key/parameter independence.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :). In general, is it ok to use the same symmetric key and iv to encrypt all my messages or is it better to create a new set of symmetric keys and iv's each time (and just share that before sending the message)?